# Is there a way to combine the following two list comprehensions?

Tags: python, list

I have a list of "point_objects", from which I build locx and locy. Please see below. Can these two list comprehensions be brought to just a single line?

```
self.locx = [pobj.x for pobj in point_objects]
self.locy = [pobj.y for pobj in point_objects]
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask] I guess the question is supposed to be the title (there should be an actual question in the post as well). But I can't make any sense out of that. What do you mean by "combine"? Which comprehensions are "the following"? Do you want to use one comprehension to compute `self.locx` and `self.locy` at the same time?

Comment: What do you mean by combine?, deque list or array are very different things do you want to combine this things?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the title, I understood that you want one line that computes both of these. You can use `zip()`:

```py
self.locx, self.locy = zip(*((pobj.x, pobj.y) for pobj in point_objects))
```

Comment: Thank you. Could you please explain the use of * here?

Comment: `*`, the star operator, in this case, is the unpacking operator. See this in the Python documentation: [Expression Lists](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#expression-lists:~:text=An%20asterisk%20*%20denotes%20iterable%20unpacking.).

Comment: Thank you @pigrammer. That helped. The link was broken, but i read about the unpacking operator.